# Highcharts: how to create a simple one-axe timeline with events

Tags: highcharts, timeline

I am looking for the most simple chart, and not finding it in native Highcharts.

How can I use another chart type to simulate a simple time arrow with dates and events as labels smartly disposed so that they wouldn't collide?

[An example](http://www.vertex42.com/ExcelArticles/Images/timeline/Timeline-for-Benjamin-Franklin.gif)

Comment: Highcharts doesn't support dataLabels collision, so you will need to implement this on your own. The rest is just simple scatter chart with dataLabels.

Comment: Hm ok thank you. And do you know of a way to display the line between the label and the axis?

Comment: How about creating for each event different series? Then in each scatter series you will have two points, one with true value, and second one will be placed on timeline. Then simply set for scatter series `lineWidth: 1`.